# What are some tips on shortening the classpath in ant?

Tags: java, ant, classpath

When deploying my application on a Hudson Server (windows machine) , I'm having problems calling java.exe because my class-path is too long -- Windows taps out after certain length.

The `classpath` is basically hundreds of `Jar` files separated by semicolons

Assume the following classpath would be too large if each jar is explicitly listed in the classpath:

```
<path id="classpath.project">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>
```

What can I do in ant to shorten my classpath?

Comment: Look at this question about using classpath wildcards.

[Setting Multiple Jars In Java Classpath][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can google for OneJar.
If you want to do it yourself, then generate an "empty" jar file that only has a manifest. Add a "Class-Path: a.jar, another.jar, bla-blub.jar" line containing all needed jars to the manifest. (Google for "manifest Class-Path") (can be done with ant)
Provided that all jars are deployed aas usually you now only need your "empty" jar file on the classpath, as the JVM will now use the manifest to find all other jars.

Comment: Note that `-classpath` is supporting both relative and absolute paths to libs, but `Class-Path` in manifest file can utilize only relative paths. This may cause some pain when your build tools use absolute paths only (like Maven).

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 6 supports [wildcards in the classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). Specifically it supports using `*` to refer to all jar files in a given directory (note: **not** `*.jar`!):

Using `*` as the classpath means "all jar files in the current directory" and using `lib/*` means "all jar files in the directory `lib/`".

Unless you have *tons* of directories, this should be sufficient. I don't know how to make use of that fact from Ant, however.